# Show that this sum of polynomials has no zeros with positive real part

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $0 < \lambda_1 \leq \ldots \leq \lambda_n $ and $k_1, \ldots, k_n> 0$.

Let further 
$$
\begin{align}
P(x)&:=\prod_{i=1}^n (x+\lambda_i) = (x+\lambda_1)\cdot \ldots \cdot (x+\lambda_n) \\
q_i(x) &:=  \frac{P(x)}{(x+\lambda_i)}\\
S(x) &:= P(x) + \sum_{i=1}^n k_i q_i(x)
\end{align}
$$
be polynomials in the complex valued unknown $x$.

E.g. for $n=2$ we have

$$
S(x) = (x + \lambda_1)(x + \lambda_2) + k_1(x+\lambda_2) + k_2(x+\lambda_1).
$$

I suspect that S(x) has no zeros with positive real part. I tried it numerically 100 times for $n=5$ with random numbers for $x_i, \lambda_i$ and always got 5 negative real roots. (So, I guess that actually there are no non-real roots, but that is not so important.)

From [Descartes rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes'_rule_of_signs) we know that $S$ has no positive real roots (because all coefficients of $S$ are positive). But how can we exclude complex roots with positive real parts (or as a whole)?

**Update:**

For the special case $\lambda_1 =\ldots = \lambda_n =:\lambda <0$ the assertion is almost trivial. In this case we have

$$
S(x) = (x+ \lambda)^n + \sum_{i=0}^n k_i (x + \lambda)^{n-1}
 = (x + \lambda)^{n-1} (x + \lambda  + \sum_{i=0}^n k_i),
$$
i.e., we have $n-1$ zeros unchanged at $\lambda$ and one zero shifted by $\sum_{i=0}^n k_i$ to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A former professor of me suggested the following argumentation:

First, we rewrite the polynomial
$$
\begin{align}
S(x) & = \prod_{j=1}^n (x + \lambda_{j}) +
\sum_{i=1}^n k_i \cdot \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^n (x + \lambda_{j}) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( k_i \cdot  \hspace{-2mm} \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^n (x + \lambda_{j})
+ \frac{1}{n} \prod_{j=1}^n x + \lambda_{j} \right) \notag \\
&=
\sum_{i=1}^n \left( \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^n (x + \lambda_{j}) \right)\cdot
\left( \frac{x + \lambda_{i}}{n} + k_i \right) \\
&=
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\left( \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^n (x + \lambda_{j}) \right)\cdot
\left( x + \lambda_{i} + n\cdot k_i \right).
\end{align}
$$

Now we let $x = \mu e^{\alpha i}$ with $\mu, \alpha \geq 0$, i.e. $x$ is a complex number in $\mathcal Q_1$, the first quadrant of the complex plain.

Clearly, we have $x + \lambda_j \in \mathcal Q_1$.
Further, we remind a) that the angle-arguments of complex numbers add up when multiplying these complex numbers and b) that $\mathrm{arc}(\frac{1}{n} e^{i \alpha}) = \frac{\alpha}{n}$.

Now we see that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\left( \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^n (x + \lambda_{j}) \right)\cdot
\left( x + \lambda_{i} + n\cdot k_i \right) \in \mathcal Q_1
$$
holds, because it is the average of $n$ complex numbers from $\mathcal Q_1$.

Finally, $S(x)$ is just the sum of $n$ of such "averages" and thus also in $\mathcal Q_1$.
Because $k_i >0$ is a strict inequality, the value $S(x)$ can not be zero.
This proves $S(\mathcal Q_1) \neq 0$. For the fourth quadrant an analogous argument holds.